# Attachments download file format filename&ddmm

Tags: vba, outlook

The attachments are downloaded and saved to destination folder, actually the filename+todays date & month (e.g. stat2909, repo2909) and i want to add that in my script for downloading attachments so that it downloads only of todays date files. How do i add this `Dim strDate As String, strDate = Format(Now(), "ddmm")` i tried with `If UCase(Atmt.FileName) Like "stat& strDate" Or _`  but failed. How do i do that?

Right now i am using this to download attachments

```
For Each Atmt In item.Attachments
If UCase(Atmt.FileName) Like "stat*" Or _
UCase(Atmt.FileName) Like "repo*" Then
```

Comment: it would be helpful to see if your question is answered (tick the answer), or if any Problems remain!

Answer (score 0):

only tiny error:

instead of

If UCase(Atmt.FileName) Like "stat& strDate" 'here the '& strDate' part is still part of the text...

you Need

If UCase(Atmt.FileName) Like "stat" & strDate ' assuming strDate is already filled before.

Max